# Unable to use dependency from gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependencies

I am using gradle to download some dependencies like this

```
dependencies {
   providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
   compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.2.RELEASE'
   runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
   compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
   compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.1.Final'
}
```

when I run gradle dependencies I see in my **compile** configuration.

I however am unable to use annotation from javax.validation and hibernate validator.

Things I have tried

1)gradle build --refresh-dependencies

2)deleting caches using `rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/`

3)Restarting Eclipse.

Anybody has any idea how to resolve this please suggest

Answer (score 0):

So I did a little digging and found out gradle was not at fault here. The .caches folder has downloaded the dependency but eclipse was not pulling it in . Found this on a discussion board and it did the trick.

**I have apply plugin:eclipse  in my build**

It depends on how you integrate with Eclipse. If you use Gradle's 'apply plugin: eclipse', run 'gradle cleanEclipse eclipse'. If you use the STS Gradle plugin, right-click the project and choose 'Gradle - Refresh Dependencies'.